# Uncaught Error: Function already initialized

Tags: fancybox-3

I'm including FancyBox v3 into my Wordpress plugin using this enqueue function:

```
function fancyBox_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.js', array('jquery'), '3.1.20', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/lightbox.js', array( 'fancybox' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fancyBox-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.css', array(), '3.1.20', 'all');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fancyBox_enqueue_scripts');
```

When I load my page, I get an error that says:

```
Uncaught Error: fancyBox already initialized
    at Function.error (jquery.js:2)
    at jquery.fancybox.js:26
    at jquery.fancybox.js:2969
error @ jquery.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.fancybox.js:26
(anonymous) @ jquery.fancybox.js:2969
```

The FancyBox script has a check for initialization in the first few lines that's throwing the error, but I haven't initialized it anywhere else. Anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you or some plugin you are using have included fancyBox, check output to see where exactly.

If you wish, you can override how this exception is handled, for example:

```
jQuery.error = console.error;
```

Comment: If I override how the exception is handled, would it allow it to run? Where would I put that code if so?

Comment: Run `jQuery.fancybox.version` and it will return "2.1.5", so, it definitely is somewhere burred :)

Comment: btw, I found it, it is here - http://blue-elan.com/wp-content/themes/ken/js/min/theme-scripts-ck.js

Comment: If fancyBox is being initiated in my theme do I need to include it manually?

Comment: It would be best if you would remove old version of fancyBox from your theme script.